# Django Queryset many to many

Tags: django, django-queryset, manytomanyfield

I have an issue with the output of a ManyToMany query in Django

I have two classes: Investor and Fund. A Fund can have many Investors, and an Investor can be invested in multiple Funds, hence the Manytomany relationship

The objective is to show in HTML (via a template) a list per investor of all the funds in which he/she is invested.

Models.py:

```
class Fund(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__ (self):
    return self.name

class Investor(models.Model):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
investments = models.ManyToManyField(Fund)

def __str__ (self):
    return self.first_name
```

view.py:

```
def investors_overview(request):
 investors = Investor.objects.all()
 return render(request, 'funds/investors.html', {'investors_overview' : investors })
```

template:

```
{% for investor in investors_overview %}
<p>{{investor.first_name}} </p>
<p>{{investor.investments.all}} </p>
```

I would like the have as output the exact names of the various funds the investor is invested in. However, the output in HTML is not "clean" and is as as follows:

```
<QuerySet [<Fund: Fund1>, <Fund: Fund2>]>
```

Comment: You can *iterate* over the collection, and print the name (or something else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *iterate* over the `fund`s, like:

```
{% for investor in investors_overview.all() %}
    <p>{{investor.first_name}} </p>
    <p>
    {% for fund in investor.investments %}
        {{ fund }}
    {% endfor %}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

You can boost performance of the queryset, by using a `.prefetch_related(..)`:

```
def investors_overview(request):
 investors = Investor.objects.prefetch_related('investments')
 return render(request, 'funds/investors.html', {'investors_overview' : investors })
```

Comment: Hi Willem, thanks but now Ive got a TypeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable

Comment: @TDM: sorry, forgot the `.all`.